# Open-source Ubuntu Dropbox client?

Tags: linux, open-source, ubuntu, dropbox

Are there any open source actively developed free Dropbox clients for Ubuntu 15.10?

Must have basically as much of the features just as official client does. (LAN sync is not required)

I myself found Syncany but it was unusable, are there any more?

Comment: Can you tell us why Syncany was unusable?

Comment: @Tom It filled my Dropbox with cache(?) files, it did not start properly every boot and it used CPU like crazy.

Comment: @Tom In addition to that I had to recompile it to get it working because Dropbox denied their API key limitation extension (now I know why). I want something that works.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted this clarified if it lacked a certain feature you needed or something like that

Comment: There seriously aren't any?

Comment: I've looked myself to no avail, but what you could do is place a bounty on the question, [read up here for more information](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).

Comment: Can't you access Dropbox via a web browser? That may not be convenient for everything but you aren't saying what you want to use so it's difficult to help you. What features are you looking for in that client? Please read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Gilles I thought the term "Dropbox client" tells enough but I've added a few more details. The web client has no sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [Dropbox Uploader](https://www.andreafabrizi.it/2016/01/01/Dropbox-Uploader/) ([code](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader), written in shell script, GNU GPL v3), and is CLI.

To list all contents in the top-level directory:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh list
```

To list all contents in a specific folder:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh list Documents/manuals
```

To upload a local file to a remote Dropbox folder:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh upload snort.pdf Documents/manuals
```

To download a remote file from Dropbox to a local file:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh download Documents/manuals/mysql.pdf ./mysql.pdf
```

To download an entire remote folder from Dropbox to a local folder:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh download Documents/manuals ./manuals
```

To create a new remote folder on Dropbox:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh mkdir Documents/whitepapers
```

To delete an entire remote folder (including all its contents) on Dropbox:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh delete Documents/manuals
```

It works with MacOSX, Windows/Cygwin, and Unix.

Other nice features:

- File and recursive directory download
- File and recursive directory upload
- Support for the official Dropbox API
- No password required or stored

Main drawback:

- cannot resume upload in case it gets stopped

Example: recursive upload:

[image]